# Le mot « susmentionné »

Tags: vocabulaire

Est-ce que j'utilise ce mot correctement?

> La maison de Tom est blanche, grande, blah blah blah blah…
>   De plus, la maison **susmentionné** a une piscine.

Comment: Attention à la traduction mot à mot (sans oublier que *..'s* n'est pas français) "*La maison de Tom est blanche*, grande, bla-bla,..." (on trouvera plus facilement blabla ou bla-bla en français qu'avec un *h* après le *a*.

Comment: If your second sentence is quite close to the first one (not to much bla bla bla) , you could say "De plus, elle a aussi une piscine" , where "elle" stands for "the house". `susmentionné` is really really formal...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Susmentionné* est rarement utilisé dans le langage courant, techniquement c'est correct mais on dirait plus simplement :

> La maison (de Tom) a aussi une piscine.

De plus il faudrait écrire *la maison susmentionné**e*** (accord de l'adjectif).

Comment: Ah d'accord.  Mais, je peux utiliser ce mot dans un essai pour mon classe et Je serai correcte?  Pourtant, comme vous avez dit, ce mot juste est rarement utilisé?

Comment: C'est juste, mais dans le contexte, pas approprié.
Ce mot n'est pas courant, il est plutôt utilisé dans des textes de types juridique ou encore administratif.

Answer (score 2):

*Susmentionné* est plutôt un terme du langage légal. À première vue, *elle*, *cette dernière* et autres formules avec des pronoms seraient suffisantes. Si tu tiens à dire *la maison*, alors *la maison en question* est une formulation beaucoup plus proche du langage courant.